# PHP: Call a javascript under echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I was trying to call a javascript using PHP, but the confirmation message is not displaying...

Here's my code:

```
echo "<button type='submit' name='deletePlaylist[]' value='" . $row['id']."' onClick='myFunction()' style='border: 0; background: transparent; cursor: pointer;'><img src='image/delete.png' /></button> ";
```

Here's my javascript:

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x;
var r=confirm("Press a button!");
if (r==true)
  {
 window.location='booking_delete.php'"
  }
else
  {
  x="You pressed Cancel!";
  }

}
</script>
```

I'm newbie in javascript with php...

When the user click the button OKAY it will proceed to another page **'booking_delete.php'** where in that page it will delete the data that the user choose to delete.

Thank you.

Comment: If the problem is with the JS not running, then show us the client side code … not the server side code that generates it.

Comment: Check if generated HTML code is Ok + check if your Javascript console shows errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PHP` code is fine! but you have made `two` mistakes in your `javascript code`.

```
window.location='booking_delete.php'"
                                    ^1) double qoutes closing but not opening
                                     2) No terminator(Semicolon i.e ';')
```

It should be like this:

```
window.location = 'booking_delete.php';
```

Comment: The quotes are the real problem. Missing the semi-colon is generally considered bad practise, but it won't cause a problem in this particular case.

Comment: @MoeedFarooqui....sorry..thanks for correcting me.... but its not going to the form of booking_delete.php';...is something wrong??

Comment: I have checked it is going on `booking_delete.php` once clicked on `OK`, what problem you are facing

Comment: @PrincessToledo is your button inside a form?

The type="submit" in your button might be taking you to the action url of the form

Comment: @RubenSerratePardo..yes I have...here's my code <form name='form' method='post' action="">.... when I click okay its just stay in the page its not going to the booking_delete.

Comment: change `<button` to `<input type="submit" `.. and so on

Comment: If you have any other fields in your form they are not being sent to booking_delete.php, so I guess you don't really need the form. Try and get rid of it.

Your problem is that your button is submitting the form so your redirection is not having any effect.

Comment: @MoeedFarooqui...I didn't used the "submit" because the button is have an image... I already tried that before but its not working [not clickable] thats why i changed to <button

Comment: @RubenSerratePardo... The booking_delete, this is my deleting code... So i need to proceed to booking_delete so the data will be deleted...

Answer (score -1):

change your button type into button, and change your call, i'd write it like this :

```
echo "<button type='button' name='deletePlaylist[]' value='" . $row['id']."' onClick='javascript:{myFunction();}' style='border: 0; background: transparent; cursor: pointer;'><img src='image/delete.png' /></button> ";
```

Comment: `javascript:{myFunction();}`!? Why would you add a label when there is no loop to break from, and a block (when there is no if/while/etc)?!

Comment: @Gar...hey thanks for the help..its displaying but when I tried to hit the okay button its not going to the "booking_delete.php"

Comment: change the line "window.location" into : window.location.href='booking_delete.php'

Comment: could you check if you have errors in your javascript console ?

Comment: @Gar..there's no error... Its just like closing the page when I click the ok button..

Comment: ok may i suggest you then to use a normal submit, and an anonyous function to confirm it ? that means you have to wrap that button inside a form, do you get the point ?

Answer (score -1):

```
Try This Code:

<?php 

echo "<button type='submit' name='deletePlaylist[]' value='" . $row['id']."' onClick='myFunction()' style='border: 0; background: transparent; cursor: pointer;'><img src='image/delete.png' /></button> ";

?>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x;
var r=confirm("Press a button!");
if (r==true)
  {
 window.location='booking_delete.php'; // You made a mistake in this line.
  }
else
  {
  x="You pressed Cancel!";
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: @user2782884..thanks for the help also working but its not going to the page of booking_delete...